# How to construct a NSURLRequest with XML format argument?

Tags: ios, xml, uiwebview

I want to construct a NSURLRequest like this:

```
NSString *str = @"http://example.com?format=xml&data=<token>123456</token>";
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:str];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
```

It seems the NSURL don't support XML format arguments`data=<token>123456</token>`,
So it returns nil.

But I have to load this kind of url in my UIWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about if you "escape" those special characters using [`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a)?

```
NSString *str = @"http://example.com?format=xml&data=<token>123456</token>";
NSString *escaped = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escaped]];
```